# After Effects Layer Properties Interaction

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

Just new here :)

I want to be able to do 2(-ish) things on my layers on After Effects.

(Layer 1 = l1; Layer 2 = L2; Blur amount = BA)

```
Increase L2’s BA whenever I increase L1’s BA. (Or the opposite, decrease BAs)
Change L2’s opacity to 0% if L2’s BA is 0 and it’s opacity to 100% if L2’s BA is >1 or <1.
```

Essentially I’m trying to make these individual properties interact with each other without using too much slider controls.

Answer (score 1):

For the blur, just use the pick-whip to link the properties. you might want to read up on how to [link properties with expressions](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/edit-expressions.html#link-expressions) using the pick whip.

For the opacity, you'll need some javascript. what you want to do is set the opacity of L1 to **if** L2 blur is 0 then 0, or **else** if it's not  equal to 1 then 100%.

```
let L2 = thisComp.layer("layer 2 name");
//use the pick whip to get the actual property name here
let blurAmt = l2.effect("Blur effect name")("Blurriness or whatever"); 
//set the opacity to 0 if bluriness is 0 '===' means 'exactly equal to'
if (blurAmt === 0){
    0
} else if (blurAmt != 1) { //'!=' means 'not equal to'
    100
} else {
    ???? // you haven't specified what you want the opacity to be if L2's blur is 1
}
```